# Pseudocode to Logic[Predicate Logic in CS]

Tags: logic, computer-science, pseudocode, predicate

We try to translate a very simple program in pseudo-code to Predicate Logic.
The program is straightforward and does not contain loops. (sequential)

It only consists of assignments of variables and if-else statements.

Unfortunately we do not have any good information provided to solve the problem. It would be great if someone has some

- examples "conversions" of simple 5liner code snippets or
- links to sources for free information, which describe the topic on the surface level. *( We only do predicate and prepositional logic and do not want to dive much deeper in the logic space. )*

Kind regards

---

UPDATE:
After enough research I found the solution and can share it inc. examples.
The trick is to think of the program state as a set of all our arbitrary variables inc. a program counter which stands for the current instruction to be executed.

```
x = input;
x = x*2;
if (y>0)
x = x∗y ;
else
x = y;
```

We will form the Predicate P(x,i,y,pc).
From here we can build promises e.g.:

```
∀i∀x∀y(P (x, i, y, 1) => P (i, i, y, 2))
∀i∀x∀y(P (x, i, y, 2) => P (x ∗ 2, i, y, 3))
∀i∀x∀y(P (x, i, y, 3) ∧ y > 0 =⇒ P (x ∗ y, i, y, 4))
∀i∀x∀y(P (x, i, y, 3) ∧ ¬y > 0 =⇒ P (y, i, y, 4))
```

By incrementing the Program counter we make sure that the promises follow in order. Now we are able to define make a proof when given a premise for the Input e.g. P(x,4,7,1).

Comment: Can you provide an example of the sort of input (in pseudo-code) and output (in predicate logic) that you are expecting?

Comment: I am sorry I am not allowed to specify more since it is related to university. That is why I am only searching for information on the top level to the topic or general examples.

Comment: But could you make up an example? What would the input look like? What would the output look like? Without that we really can't provide any advice.

Comment: I was able to give an example and a solution now. Guess my explanation was not so clear. Thank you anyway!